# Is the top of an iceberg floating above the waterlevel equal to the expanding of the whole iceberg?

Tags: thermodynamics, buoyancy, fluid-statics, states-of-matter

When water freezes it expands and is getting less dense. But is this expansion of the total iceberg equal to the top of an iceberg floating just above sealevel?

[image]

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Have another go...?

Comment: with expanding of the total iceberg I mean the increase of volume of that piece of ice due to crystalization of water into ice.

Comment: @Marijn Would this title "Is the volume above water of an iceberg equal to the increased volume it got when it froze?" work?

Comment: Yes I think so.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. An equivalent way of saying this is that if an ice cube (or iceberg...) melts, the water level remains unchanged. (I.e.: the melted iceberg exactly fits in the 'hole' it creates underwater.)

To see this, think of what is holding the ice up: it's buoyancy, which is the upward force due to the pressure of the surrounding water. This force is directly proportional to the volume that the object occupies below water level. (This is conceptually simple: imagine replacing the object by water [till the surface level], then of course the water is stable, meaning the weight of the water equals the buoyancy force, and of course the weight of the water is directly proportional to the volume.) Now the weight of the ice = weight of the water that it would melt into, which means that the melting process will keep the volume under the surface level unchanged. This means we're done: the volume of the iceberg under water corresponds to the volume of the melted iceberg.

Comment: Consequence: If the Arctic (mostly floating ice) melts sea levels won't rise significantly. But if the Antarctic melts (ice on landmass) they'll rise about something like 50 meters

Comment: Even if the arctic melts it would have big consequences, since it is sweet water melting into salty water (and the density of salty water is higher than sweet water, such that things are more easily lifted up by buoyancy [think of the Dead Sea])

Answer (score 0):

Imagine a portion of the(liquid) water. It will be in equilibrium with the whole fluid. The buoyancy force $E_1$ over this portion matches its weight. Now freezes this same portion. The buoyancy force $E_2$ on the ice equals its weight. Since the weights are the same, the buoyancy forces are equal. This implies the volume of fluid dislocated in both situations is the same. Therefore, the volume of the ice above the liquid level is exactly the increased volume the portion gained when it froze.